# Emacs ignores frame-title-format

Tags: emacs

My emacs (GNU Emacs 23.0.91.2 (powerpc-ibm-aix5.3.0.0, X toolkit)) ignores the following parameters:

```
(setq default-frame-alist "%b")
(setq icon-title-format "%b")
(setq frame-title-format "%b")
```

What I get is `<filename> (on HOSTNAME)`. It is irrelevant how my frame-title-format looks like. Emacs always adds `"(on HOSTNAME)"`.

Anybody an idea why this happens?

Answer (score 0):

1. Where/when are you setting such variables?  Give a recipe of what you have done.
2. You do ***NOT*** want to set `default-frame-alist` to a string!  (`C-h v default-frame-alist` to see what it is.)  But I suspect that you did not really do that and you mistyped whatever you really did do.